# Auto-creating Queues in djangorq

Tags: django-rq

RQ normally creates queues [on the fly](https://python-rq.org/docs/).

> With RQ, you don’t have to set up any queues upfront, and you don’t have to specify any channels, exchanges, routing rules, or whatnot. You can just put jobs onto any queue you want

However, when using the [DJangoRQ Wrapper](https://github.com/rq/django-rq) attempts to use a queue not enumerated in the Django settings.py throws an exception.

```
NoRedisConnectionException('Could not resolve a Redis connection')
```

*How do you configure django-rq to use the behaviour of regular RQ?*

I have valid connection options (HOST, PORT, DB etc..) on the default queue, but these do not seem to be inherited to other queues.
*How can I keep DRY and specify these only once?*